# sHow does modbus read non-contiguous addresses？

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, asp.net-core, modbus

I use the class library EasyModbus. When I want to read continuous data, the code is as follows:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ModbusClient modbusClient = new ModbusClient("127.0.0.1", 502);    //Ip-Address and Port of Modbus-TCP-Server
            modbusClient.Connect();                                                    //Connect to Server
           
            int[] readHoldingRegisters = modbusClient.ReadHoldingRegisters(0, 123);    //Read 10 Holding Registers from Server, starting with Address 1

            // Console Output

            for (int i = 0; i < readHoldingRegisters.Length; i++)
                Console.WriteLine("Value of HoldingRegister " + (i + 1) + " " + readHoldingRegisters[i].ToString());
            modbusClient.Disconnect();                                                //Disconnect from Server
            Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
```

I know that the Modbus TCP/IP protocol has a maximum frame data length limit of 260 bytes, and I can divide a large number of addresses (assuming there are 10,000 addresses).

However, the above codes are only continuous addresses, and most of the modbus addresses are not continuous in practice. How can I read them in batches to improve reading efficiency?

Answer (score 0):

The [MODBUS Application Protocol Specification](https://modbus.org/docs/Modbus_Application_Protocol_V1_1b3.pdf) defines a range of function codes (and permits additional, user defined codes). The functions defined for requesting registers/coils provide the option to request one value or a contiguous range (this means requests are of a fixed length which simplifies processing; important on resource constrained devices).

Given that limitation you have the option to:

- read a range that includes all required registers (and ignore those you do no need). Note that some controllers will return an error if the range includes undefined registers.
- make multiple requests (for ranges or single values).

The best approach will depend upon the specific situation (and your requirements; sometimes its important to read related values in a single transaction). However it is important to note that you do not need to connect/disconnect between each read (you may choose to just leave the connection open but would need to handle reconnections) e.g.:

```
modbusClient.Connect(); // Connect to Server
           
int[] readHoldingRegisters1 = modbusClient.ReadHoldingRegisters(0, 10);    //Read 10 Holding Registers from Server, starting with Address 1

int[] readHoldingRegisters2 = modbusClient.ReadHoldingRegisters(20, 10);   //Read 10 Holding Registers from Server, starting with Address 21

modbusClient.Disconnect();
```

Note that some controllers provide ways around this (by enabling the remapping of registers or via User-Defined Functions).

Answer (score 0):

Modbus is a very simple protocol that can only read one or a few contiguous bits or registers.

If you want to read many variable values in a single request think about using OPC UA instead of Modbus, although OPC UA is much more complicated ...